# Get changed files using Azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting this error message

> fatal: ambiguous argument '@~': unknown revision or path not in the
> working tree.

Use `--` to separate paths from revisions, like this:

```
git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]
```

while executing the

```
git diff --name-only @~ @
```

Trying the get the file which is changed in a PR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git diff command requires at least depth 2 to get the changed files.

The cause of the issue can be related to the fetch depth of the Pipeline repo.

By default, the Shallow fetch of the pipeline repo is  1 by default.

You can try to set the **fetchDepth** to **0** ,**2** or **>2** in YAML Pipeline.

For example:

**YAML Pipeline**

```
steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
```

Or you can navigate to **YAML Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources -> Shallow fetch**.  You can unselect the option.

[image]

[image]

**Classic Pipeline:**

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Shallow fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#shallow-fetch)

**Update:**

```
steps:
- checkout: self 
  fetchDepth: 2 
- task: PowerShell@2 
  inputs: 
   targetType: 'inline' 
   script: |
     $changedFiles = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
     echo $changedFiles
```

**Update1:**

You can try to add the **workingDirectory** in the powershell task.

For example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self 
  fetchDepth: 2 

- task: PowerShell@2 
  inputs: 
   workingDirectory:  $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Yourreponanme
   targetType: 'inline' 
   script: |
     $changedFiles = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
     echo $changedFiles
```

Comment: I have changed the Shallow fetch depth as 2, still I am getting the same error.

        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 1  # Shallow fetch only the latest commit
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $changedFiles = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD

Comment: @Sweta   You need to set the **fetchDepth** to **2** in the yaml code. From your YAML code you have set it to 1. You need to set it to 2.For example: steps: - checkout: self **fetchDepth: 2** - task: PowerShell@2 inputs: targetType: 'inline' script: | $changedFiles = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD

Comment: @Sweta Check the update in the answer.

Comment: Getting this error 
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Comment: @Sweta Can you share more yaml code sample? Then I can check this issue further

Comment: Are you checking multiple repos in the YAML Pipeline?

Comment: steps:
- checkout: self  
            fetchDepth: 2
          - task: Powershell@2
            inputs: 
              targetType: 'inline' 
              script: |
                  $changedFiles = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
                  echo $changedFiles

It's the same what you shared

Comment: No, I am checking only one

Comment: @Sweta You can try to add the argument: **workingDirectory:  $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Yourreponanme** in the powershell task and check if it can work.  You need to use your repo name to replace the reponame

Comment: You can check the update1 in the answer

Comment: The error means that the working folder is not in the correct path. You can also run **ls** to confirm the current files in the **$(build.sourcesdirectory)** and then you can set the correct path in **workingDirectory**

Comment: the code you suggested worked, but the other step where we are building the project is failing


MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: C:\__w\1\s\dirs.proj
##[error]Process 'MSBuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to switch back to same directory after I got the list of changes file

Comment: @Sweta To confirm the specific file path of the dirs.proj, you can add the command in powershell task: **Get-ChildItem $(build.sourcesdirectory)  -Filter *.proj-Recurse | % { $_.FullName }** Then you can use the output path in the vsbuild or msbuild task

Comment: Yeah, I will close this one.